# Call function on previously selected radio button with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Hello I have some radio buttons with different radio groups name. I want to call the function on the previously selected radio button for that specific group.

If I check the radio button then select the different radio button from the same group. I want call the function or add class on the previously selected radio button of the same group in jQuery.

Here is the example code -

```
RadioGroup1Button 1: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup1' /><br />
RadioGroup1Button 2: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup1' /><br />
RadioGroup2Button 1: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup2' /><br />
RadioGroup2Button 2: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup2' /><br />
RadioGroup2Button 3: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup2' /><br />
```

Please help

Comment: can you show what you have tried.

Comment: You want to check multiple radios with the same name? --- Try checkboxes instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this you want?

```
$("input:radio").on("mousedown", function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if ($("input:radio[name='" + name + "']:checked").length == 1 && $(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
    $("input:radio[name='" + name + "']").removeClass("PrevChecked");
    $("input:radio[name='" + name + "']:checked").addClass("PrevChecked");
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("input:radio").on("mousedown", function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if ($("input:radio[name='" + name + "']:checked").length == 1 && $(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
    $("input:radio[name='" + name + "']").removeClass("PrevChecked");
    $("input:radio[name='" + name + "']:checked").addClass("PrevChecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
RadioGroup1Button 1: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup1' /><br /> RadioGroup1Button 2: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup1' /><br /> RadioGroup2Button 1: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup2' /><br /> RadioGroup2Button 2: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup2'
/><br /> RadioGroup2Button 3: <input type='radio' name='radioGroup2' /><br />
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thank you

Comment: @Akshay No problem, Happy to help